# Game for Apple TV appears tilted on the big screen

Tags: ios, airplay, apple-tv

Since a few years back I have a "iPhone is the controller, game screen displayed on TV by way of Apple TV and Air Play" project slowly going. It's like a space-shooter-maze kind of game, except there is no shooting and the objective is to steer a spaceship to find the boss (which is a pic of my then ~1 year old son). Like a NES game without the NES.

Now when I run the stuff for the first time in like a year or so, the controller, which is basically using a SpriteKit scene down the line, is tilted 90 degrees in the right OR left direction. The "OR" depends on what orientation my iPhone 6 Plus is in when the app starts. So the game only takes up half of the tv screen now - because it's tilted - and even a lay man can see that something fishy is going on because the text is not the normal horizontal text you are reading now, it's tilted.

Did something change recently, like with iOS 8 and how hooking up additional UIScreen:s work? I rarely touch this project, so I forget how everything work most of the time I do something with it again after a long hiatus. Anyone experienced this and know where to start digging?

Answer (score 0):

Poking around, it seems that the app itself and what is displayed on the handheld device/controller (the iPhone) must/should be portrait only. If the app is launched in landscape mode, the screen display on the tv will also be "tilted", without the tv itself being tilted... and things get out of order. I set portrait only just by clicking around in the target->device orientation checkboxes.

This is kind of unwanted because the a normal video game controller is held in a landscape position and this was the way I always used it. I don't know what made this work differently, maybe it's the iPhone 6 Plus with landscape support at the home screen level, or maybe iOS 8 or whatever.

<s>So there are basically two options here.</s>

- Design the controller as portrait, but already in the design put everything tilted. The bottom left steering cross would have to be put top left, tilted 90 degrees to the right for a fake "landscape right" setting. Might be less of a pain than doing the same thing to the tv screen instead.
- Continue with the use of real landscape mode for the controller, and use some anti-tilt rotation by setting a new rotated transform of the tv controller's view's transform. (I tried this, it seemed like it needed a translation as well, so I gave up. Still might work.)

**Update: I found a better solution:**

1. Allow landscape right, landscape left AND portrait rotations of the app. (In that order, if you intend to launch the controller in landscape mode - but portrait has to be in there.)
2. In the subclass of UIViewController that controls what's going on upon your tv, return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` in `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. The tv controller must be run in "portrait" mode, which for a tv controller would mean the "default" mode, which for the eye looks like the normal landscapish mode. A landscaped tv controller would mean a tilted view, and we don't want that. Yes this is weird but maybe logical. Oh, and in the subclass of UIViewController for the hand controller, I return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape` so as not to support portrait mode. The user likely launches the controller in portrait mode (especially on any iPhone other than 6 Plus) and if we supported that he/she would maybe think the controller can only be used in portrait mode, and that is very inconvenient when playing video games.